# Use instance's method in generic method

Tags: c#, generics

My code goes like this:

```
public T ReadState<T>(string file_path)
{
    string file_content = ...read file..from file_path...        
    T state = ...xml deserialize...
    state.SetSomething(); //  <--the problem is here <--
    return state;
}
```

I want to use this generic method on a various object types. **Of course, they all implementing the `SetSomething()` method**

Currently, the compiler complains:

> 'T' does not contain a definition for SetSomething()...

TIA!

Comment: T needs to Implement an INTERFACE, or you need to use reflection to cast it to the strongly typed object that has the method on it. Which way would you like seen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Of course, they all implementing the `SetSomething()` method

Then you should tell the compiler that:

- Create an interface with the `SetSomething()` method
- Make all the relevant types implement the interface
- Constrain `T` to implement that interface:

  ```
  public T ReadState<T>(string file_path) where T : IYourNewInterface
  ```

If you *can't* make the types all implement an interface, the simplest solution is probably to use dynamic typing:

```
((dynamic) state).SetSomething();
```

The interface solution is *far* cleaner though, where feasible.

Comment: Jon Skeet Both solutions works like charm! The dynamic cast is good enough for me :)